# Integrate azure logic app in ci cd azure devops

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure environment, I Have a `logic app` inside which i am making some calls to azure functions...

I want to figure out how to integrate my logic app in my `ci cd pipeline on azure devops`, the way i can update it each time i make a commit on it from `visual studio 2019`.

I have tried to create my `azure logic app` from azure **portal** but i couldn't create a link between it and my release task.

Every time i need to make changes manually to reflect my needs.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do you try the solution given by Haithem? If it is helpful to you ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create the logic app from `Visual studio`.

In order to do that, you will need to install the extension `Azure Logic App Tools for Visual Studio`as following:[image]

This will allow you to have the `LogicApp.json` file in your repository wich will be incremented each time you modify it.

The next step is to create a `release task` on azure devops called `"create or update ressource group"` like mentioned below:

[image]

Finally, you can refer to this détailed [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blX-xpN8jFQ) where you will find all the inbetween steps to realise what you want.

Hope this helps,
HK

Comment: i use visual studio 2019 and the image above shows visual studio 2017 extension .
is it the same ?

Comment: @ihebCH yes it is the same extension for visual studio 2019. found under tools -> extension and updates